# @media print css

Tags: javascript, css

Talvez essas perguntas podem ser tachadas como "idiota", mas acreditem em mim, preciso muito perguntar isso aqui por que não encontrei em nenhum lugar na internet e quem puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato...

Existe alguma maneira de fazer 2 (dois)  ou mais "@media print" do css? Por exemplo, eu fiz um para imprimir uma determinada div, agora quero imprimir outra div totalmente diferente com outras configurações de formatação, como eu faria usando o proprio @media print?

Aproveitando a pergunta, existe alguma maneira de formatar a div como desejado antes de mandar imprimir pelo javascript, não gostei da impressão do javascript, não vem quase nada do que foi feito na página além da escrita pura. '-'

```
@media print {
body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.noneImprime
{
    display: none;
}
#imprime, #imprime * {
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: -160px !important;
}
#imprime
{
    width: 1100px;
}
.btn-resultado{
    display: none;
}
@page{
     size: landscape;
    }
}
```

Acima tem o código que estou usando para imprimir minha div com o ID: imprime, no entanto eu tenho outra div, que no meu caso é o conteúdo de uma modal para imprimir, como eu faço para imprimir somente o conteúdo desejado como mostra corretamente acima e no mesmo print imprimir somente o conteúdo da minha modal?
 Neste caso toda vez que eu clico no botão designado ele vai imprimir sempre a mesma div.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pra formatar duas div's diferentes, coloque classes diferentes nela e colocar as propriedades diferentes dentro do `@media print`

Pra testar como funciona antes de gerar a impressão do javascript você pode ir na opção 'More tools > Rendering settings > Emulate media > print' da ferramenta de desenvolvedor do Chrome:

[image: Sinalização da localização da opção "Render print" dentro da ferramente de desenvolvedor do Google Chrome]

Você provavelmente vai ter que usar alguns `!important` para sobrescrever o estilo padrão da folha de impressão e como você vai fazer isso dentro do Media query de print, é bem tranquilo.

Comment: Entendi Vinicius, muito obrigado pela resposta, no entanto tenho mais uma dúvida, no meu caso uso o visibility: hidden e visible para mostrar na folha de impressão somente o conteudo desejado, para fazer isso com duas divs diferentes acho que não dá né, por que ou mostra uma ou mostra a outra.

Comment: Cara, se for possível edita sua pergunta com o código que fica mais fácil de entender isso, mas aí é questão de atribuir uma id ou uma classe diferente e trabalhar com as regras CSS.

Comment: Editei o post, acho que não to sabendo explicar direito, de qualquer forma eu agradeço muito a sua ajuda.

Comment: Hm, a explicação tá meio complicada de entender pra ser sincero, não sei se o HTML ajudaria, mas não seria só uma questão de forçar um display no conteúdo do modal?

Comment: Não, mas a sua resposta está correta, obrigado por sua ajuda, obrigado mesmo.